# Form submitting when pressing enter in Textarea

Tags: jquery, forms

I've been trying various methods to get a form to submit when hitting the enter key.  I know it works with an input field, but because this is going to be a comment, it needs to be a text area.

This is what I currently have for the form to submit with a button.

```
$('.messageSubmit').live('click', function(){
    var name = $(this).siblings('.messageTextarea').val();
    var theid = $(this).attr('data-the_id');
    var dataString = name;

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/"+$(this).attr('data-the_id')+"/comments?"+hash,
        type: "POST",
        data: "text="+dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            // finish load
            console.log(data, dataString, 'fail');
        },
        error: function(data) {
            var username = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('iguser'));
            var profilepic = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('iguserimg'));
            //console.log(data, dataString, 'succ');

            $('.box[data-the_id="' + theid + '"]').children('.postMessage').children('.messageComments').append('<li><img class="commentUserImg" src="' + profilepic + '"><div class="commentUser">' + username + '</div><div class="commentText">' + dataString + '</div></li>');

            $('.messageTextarea').val(''); // Remove comment from TextArea
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

It works like it should.  I want to remove the submit button and just have the form submit when a user hits the enter key.  I know some people advise against this, but the users on this website will be used to hitting enter from Facebook and such.

I've tried methods such at this, but it none seem to work.

```
$('.messageTextarea').keydown(function() {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        this.form.submit();
        return false;
     }
});
```

Here is my form code

```
<form>
   <textarea class="messageTextarea" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=\'\';" onblur="if(this.value==\'\')this.value=this.defaultValue;">Write your comment here...</textarea>
    <input type="submit" data-the_id="' + theid + '" name="submit" class="messageSubmit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit your comment">
 </form>
```

Any help would be great.  Also, if anyone knows how to add an if function that will prevent the form from submitting with the current default value in the Textarea, that would be awesome.  Currently, with how the textarea is set up now, if you just hit submit, it will submit *Write your comment here...*

Thanks

**EDIT:  Could a work around be... Having an button to submit, like normal, but have it hidden, and when you hit enter it triggers a call for that button?  But then... I'd run into the same problem of enter doing nothing in the textarea except break into a new line...**

Comment: It's never a good idea to modify the way common elements function.  Users will expect that textarea allows using the enter key.  Then again, stack overflow does this so... grain of salt

Comment: That was how I first approached this problem, but the only users on this site will be those of instagram and facebook.  I figured they'd know what to do when seeing a comment field.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6vXf/6/)

HTML:

```
<form>
   <textarea class="messageTextarea">Write your comment here...</textarea>

 </form>​
```

JS:

```
       $('.messageTextarea').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this.form).submit()
        return false;
     }
}).focus(function(){
    if(this.value == "Write your comment here..."){
         this.value = "";
    }

}).blur(function(){
    if(this.value==""){
         this.value = "Write your comment here...";
    }
});

$("form").submit(function(){
       var name = $(this).siblings('.messageTextarea').val();
    var theid = $(this).attr('data-the_id');
    var dataString = name;

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/"+$(this).attr('data-the_id')+"/comments?",
        type: "POST",
        data: "text="+dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            // finish load
            console.log(data, dataString, 'fail');
        },
        error: function(data) {
            var username = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('iguser'));
            var profilepic = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('iguserimg'));
            //console.log(data, dataString, 'succ');

            $('.box[data-the_id="' + theid + '"]').children('.postMessage').children('.messageComments').append('<li><img class="commentUserImg" src="' + profilepic + '"><div class="commentUser">' + username + '</div><div class="commentText">' + dataString + '</div></li>');

            $('.messageTextarea').val(''); // Remove comment from TextArea
        }
    });

    return false;
});
​
​
```

​

Comment: So this worked in the fiddle.. But I can't get it working for me.  Should I place my AJAX inside of the If?

Comment: It worked only after removing input button. try to remove input button.

Comment: But the ajax, should that still go in this?

Comment: Yeah... but it's still not working... I have to make sure this isn't just a user error...  All of my code, except for the form, is in a function that I am recalling on the page.  Could that effect it at all?

Comment: I updated my code check have look again. Sorry, I did not get you try to say.

Comment: This seemed to work.  I Just have to tweak my current code a bit that gets instagram data to accept this.  I'll mark this as an answer.  THank you.

Answer (score 27):

I think you would also want to give users ability to go to new line using shift.

```
$('.messageTextarea').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && ! e.shiftKey) {
        // your AJAX call
    }
});
```

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/almirsarajcic/Gd8PQ/

It worked for me.

Also, you need to remove that submit button you currently have.

Comment: I feel like this is close, and I see how the AJAX should be in the function, but again, it doesn't work...

Comment: Way simpler and neater than the actual answer +1

Comment: Excellent! With the added benefit of <Shift>+<Enter> for newline.

Answer (score 3):

try it this way

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <textarea></textarea>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('textarea').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {

            this.form.submit();
            return false;
         }
    });
</script>
```

I tested it, and it worked

I added only the parameter `event` to the function header

Comment: I've tried it this way as well, it just adds a new break as an enter key would be expected too.

Comment: well, have you even saw the parameter `event` in function header?

Comment: Yes I saw it.  It still functioned as an enter rather than a submit.

Comment: gime a moment, I'll check this

Comment: I still can't get it... I've added this code outside of the commenting function, inside, i've even changed the form submit to just a console log and that didn't even work..