# Read AJAX post content using JAVA socket server

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I set up a JAVA socket server that is able to get everything from a html < form >. But when it comes to AJAX post, the server can only get the POST event, but it cannot read the "data" inside AJAX post. The following is the html code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#submit').click(function() {
//information to be sent to the server

info = $('#foo').val();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://10.0.0.3:8888',
  data: ({foo: info}),
  //crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'json'
});

return false;       
});

});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<label>Text</label>
<textarea id="foo"></textarea>

<button id="submit">Submit via Ajax</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea why this is happening, any suggestion?

Thank you

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Update**

**Java Server Code**

```
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8888);
    Socket s = ss.accept();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while (!(inputLine = in.readLine()).equals(""))
        System.out.println(inputLine);

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
    pw.println("aa");

    s.close();
    ss.close();
```

**What I got at server is like:**

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.109.3.184:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 58
Accept: */*
Origin: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

The content does not appear...

Comment: Can you show an example of the html form that worked?

Comment: Is this "socket server" your own code? Can you provide sample? As to me it looks, like you're reading only request headers, but not the content, i.e. everything that goes after \r\n\r\n.

Comment: why are you trying to do it using java socket server? are you trying websocket or bosh or any other connection?

Comment: @Kevin The example is directly submit the form without using AJAX.

Comment: @Cromax Thanks, I changed the code (as updated) to read in loop. But the content does not show up.

Comment: @java seeker Yeah, if socket server does not work, I'll turn to other ways.

Comment: @user3267738 the example you gave is missing the form tags. That's what i'm interested in.

Comment: @Kevin I am also interested in whether "form tag" is a must. In my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21539305/use-ajax-to-send-html5-textarea-directly-without-html-form?noredirect=1#comment32526719_21539305, everyone said form tag is unnecessary.

Comment: it isn't necessary for ajax. But, you said it works doing a normal post. I want to see the form tags to see if your ajax matches the way you were sending the normal post.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I just changed the method "post" to "get" and it works!

Comment: Your while-loop condition is incorrect. It should test for null, not empty string. Note, that in HTTP between headers and content there's an empty line. Your code actually stops displaying request data after reading headers. GET method request includes all form parameters in URL. With POST method data is sent as request body, right after headers (you will need extra parsing for this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST data in HTTP request come as a request body, which is separated from head by empty line like this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.1.1:80
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 29
Content-Type: text/json

{"id":123,"name":"something"}
```

So your server code should (more or **less**) ;-) look like this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

String line;
List<String> headers = new LinkedList<>();
StringBuilder body = null;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    //- Here we test if we've reach the body part.
    if (line.isEmpty() && body == null) {
        body = new StringBuilder();
        continue;
    }
    if (body != null) {
        body.append(line).append('\n');
    }
    else {
        headers.add(line);
    }
}

System.out.println("--- Headers ---");
for (String h : headers) {
    System.out.println(h);
}
System.out.println("--- Body ---");
System.out.println(body != null ? body.toString() : "");
```

Please note, that this code is only for test purposes. You can not assume, that body is a text (at least you should verify Content-Type header) and you can safely read it into StringBuilder or if it is safe at all to load it in whole into memory (at least you should verify Content-Length header). Despite of those headers you should expect the worst and during reading perform some sanity checks.

Comment: Yeah, you are totally right. Just one more thing: when I do AJAX "POST", why the body can only be received by server after webpage is reloaded?

Comment: I doubt it actually works like you described. Imagine you have form with one text input where you typed `Joe` and after you send it to the server, you want to send response with `Hello, Joe` (using this form input) in the HTML --- how could page be reloaded BEFORE server gets request? First it need to get the request, then it can send response. Maybe it happens, that your log output gets cached and is flushed after page is reloaded.

Comment: Well, these both could be possible. Thank you for leading me so far.