# URI Too Large in $.ajax({})

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have text area where I need to load image to `<img>` tag. Then, I want to post content of text area to `generate_pdf.php` to generate pdf. I have encauntered `URI Too Large`error when I post text area content by `$.ajax({})`.

**Method 1-`$.ajax({})` in `$().on("click",function(){})` of submit button**

```
<?php
//image from sql
 $image         =$array_image[0]['file'];
 $encode_img        ='"data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'"';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="../../library/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $( document ).ready(function() 
        {
            let hd = document.createElement('div'); // Create new DIV
              hd.style.display = "none";    // Hide new DIV
              hd.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#ta').value; // set its innerHTML to textarea's
              document.body.prepend(hd); // Add to body
              document.querySelector('#test').src   = <?php echo $encode_img;?>;
              document.querySelector('#ta').value   = hd.innerHTML;
              content   =$('#ta').val();
              $('#test').src                        = <?php echo $encode_img;?>;
                    //submitted uri too large 
                    //-(<form id="text_editor" name="text_editor" >)
                    $('#pdf').on("click",function() 
                    {   
                        $.ajax({
                                type:"POST",
                                url :"generate_pdf.php",
                                data:{                          
                                        'pdf    '           :content,                                                               
                                     }
                                ,
                                success:function(data)
                                {   
                                    alert('successfully posted!');                  
                                    $('#content').html(data);                                       
                                }
                            });         
                    })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="test_img" name="test_img" >
    <textarea id="ta" name="ta">
        <img alt="test" id="test">
    </textarea>     
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="pdf" id="pdf">
</form>
<div id="content" name="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then , I tried using `$.post` in `$().submit(function(event){})`. This able to submit without this error.

**Method 2-`$.post` in `$().submit(function(event){})` of form**

```
 <?php
    //image from sql
    $image          =$array_image[0]['file'];
    $encode_img     ='"data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'"';
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="../../library/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            $( document ).ready(function() 
            {
                let hd = document.createElement('div'); // Create new DIV
                  hd.style.display = "none";    // Hide new DIV
                  hd.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#ta').value; // set its innerHTML to textarea's
                  document.body.prepend(hd); // Add to body
                  document.querySelector('#test').src   = <?php echo $encode_img;?>;
                  document.querySelector('#ta').value   = hd.innerHTML;
                  content   =$('#ta').val();             
                        $("#test_img").submit(function(event)
                        {                       
                            event.preventDefault();
                            var $form   = $( this ),
                            url         = $form.attr( 'action' );
                            var posting = $.post( url, { pdf:content} );
                            posting.done(function( data ) 
                            {
                                $('#content').html(data);
                          });
                        })  
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form id="test_img" name="test_img" method="POST" action="generate_pdf.php" >
        <textarea id="ta" name="ta">
            <img alt="test" id="test">
        </textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="pdf" id="pdf">
    </form>
    <div id="content" name="content"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

`$.post` is  a shorthand for `$.ajax`.But, why method 2 able to submit successfully and first method could not? In method 1, content of data that we posting included in url. But, in second method, not included. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use `FormData` to upload large data.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Still having that error after I add `var formData = new FormData(); formData.append('pdf', content);` and pass `formData ` to ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `preventDefault()` method in `$('#pdf').on("click",function() {})` had solve error `URI Too Large`.

> The preventDefault() method stops the default action of a selected element from happening by a user. This method does not accept any parameter and works in two ways:

- It prevents a link from following the URL so that the browser can't go another page.
- It prevents a submit button from submitting a form.

Code:

```
$('#pdf').on("click",function(e) 
{
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url :"index_debug_uritoolarge_2.php",
                data:{  
                    pdf :$('#ta').val(),
                },
                success: function(data)
                                {   
                                    alert('successfully posted!');                  
                                    $('#content').html(data);
                                }
                            });         
                    })
```

Reference: [post_textarea_content_in_ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21539305/use-ajax-to-send-html5-textarea-directly-without-html-form/21539883)