# Rails 4: how to allow user to submit form with enter key, without submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4, that uses Rails' default form (I am NOT using Simple Form).

—————

**EDIT**: although the goal is fairly similar (allowing users to submit a form by pressing the enter key instead of pushing a submit button), my question is different from [Form submitting when pressing enter in Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103191/form-submitting-when-pressing-enter-in-textarea) since it relates to Rails forms, which have a particular behavior and do not work in the same way as regular jQuery forms.

—————

One of my forms allows users to create comments:

```
<%= form_for([post, post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_area :body, :placeholder => "New comment", size: "15x1" %><%= f.submit id: 'create_comment'%>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I would like to get rid of the `<%= f.submit id: 'create_comment'%>` part and allow users to submit a new comment just by pressing the enter key.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form submitting when pressing enter in Textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103191/form-submitting-when-pressing-enter-in-textarea)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use a f.text_field rather than text_area it should submit the form on enter by default.

If you need to use a textarea, then it will have to be javascript. something like:

```
$('#id_of_textarea').keypress(function(e){
      if(e.which == 13){
           $(this).closest('form').submit();
       }
    });
```