# How do I make this form submit by hitting return instead of physically hitting the "+" button *question updated*

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Ruby on rails: (really new to this)

Okay so I have this code for a form that I want to submit when I hit the return key.

I realized I have to add this code **somewhere**

reference: [Rails 4: how to allow user to submit form with enter key, without submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027838/rails-4-how-to-allow-user-to-submit-form-with-enter-key-without-submit-button)

```
$('idhere').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
         $(this).closest('form').submit();
     }
  });
```

```
<div class="input-group">
    <%= f.text_field :sample_name, class: 'form-control', hidden: true %>
    <%= f.collection_select :sample_name2, @sample, :name, :name, {include_blank: true}, {class: 'form-control selectpicker sa-sample-name', data: {'live-search' => 'true'}} %>
    <%= f.select :rank, 1..3, {}, {class: 'form-control selectpicker sa-rank', data: {'live-search' => 'true'}} %>
    <%= f.submit '   +   ', class: 'btn btn-outline-primary' %>
  </div>
```

So my first question is, do I add the id to f.select or f.submit? Only reason I ask is because in my head if the user is already clicked into f.select would they have to be able to click return from there?

And do I add the code to my application.js file or into the .erb file that I have the original code in? And if I have to add it to my application.js file is there a specific place that it needs to go?

also if I make my id:

**id: 'sa_submit'**

Would I just reference it as sa_submit or .sa_submit or :sa_submit or name-of-erb-file.sa_submit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails 4: how to allow user to submit form with enter key, without submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027838/rails-4-how-to-allow-user-to-submit-form-with-enter-key-without-submit-button)

Answer (score 1):

> And do I add the code to my application.js file or into the .erb file that I have the original code in? And if I have to add it to my application.js file is there a specific place that it needs to go?

I would use `#javascript_include_tag`. In your case, it would look something like this:

```
# in your form.html.erb file
<%= javascript_include_tag 'submit_with_return_key' %>
```

create a file called 'submit_with_return_key.js' in `app/assets/javascripts`

```
# add your JS code in the file
$('#your-id').keypress(function(e){
  if(e.which == 13){
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
   }
});
```

> Would I just reference it as sa_submit or .sa_submit or :sa_submit or name-of-erb-file.sa_submit?

For `id` you call it with `#foo`, for `class` you call it with `.foo`