# Using Markdown when form is submitted by pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, markdown

I have a Rails project, and I'd like to use Markdown in a form where the form is submitted with the enter key. I don't know if this is feasible because enter in Markdown is for new lines. Just wondering if I'm missing something. As far as I can tell, if I wanted to use Markdown, I'd have to use a submit button in my form.

If I really wanted the Markdown functionality in my form with the enter key as submit, I think I'd have to code each thing specifically. Something like:

```
$("textarea").keydown(function(e){
    // Enter was pressed with shift key
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey)
    {
        // add <br> to html $("textarea").val();
        // prevent default behavior
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Just wanted to make sure I'm barking up the right tree. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  It looks like you have a solution in your question (use shift+enter to insert newlines, and enter without shift to submit).

Comment: What's wrong with using [tab] to move focus from the textarea to the submit button and then hitting [enter]?

Comment: @Josh1billion Ideally I would use Markdown. My proposed solution creates a lot of work.

Comment: @Waylan Ideally I don't have to use a submit button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form submitting when pressing enter in Textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103191/form-submitting-when-pressing-enter-in-textarea)

Comment: @Waylan Not a duplicate but thanks for checking!

Answer (score 2):

I think if you have a form with Markdown, you definitely need a button to submit form.
If I see the multi-line text area (even without Markdown), I expect `Enter` to add a new line and not to submit the form.

Check how it works on other web-sites, for example this:

[image]

**Update**: OK, if you have to do this, here how I think it can be done.
The idea is to submit the form if Enter is pressed without Shift (and prevent the default, so Enter doesn't go to the text). And Shift+Enter inserts the new line (looks like it just works, no need to do anything).

Example code:

```js
$("textarea").keypress(function(e){
    //alert('key:' + e.keyCode);
    // Enter was pressed with shift key
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('form').submit();
    }
});
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  alert('submitted');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <form>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Since I posted, I noticed that Slack seems to use Markdown but also you submit a user's message by pressing enter. For a new line, you use shift enter. They're doing exactly what I want to do. I just have to figure out how.

Comment: @Rachel this is probably only one thing I don't like in Slack. Zillion times I've sent a half-entered message and I hate each single time it happened.

Comment: @Rachel by the way, I just tested it on the previous comment - stackoverflow submits the new comment form on Ctrl-Enter, so they both allow you to use Enter to break lines and use only keyboard to write and submit the message.

Comment: Good to know you don't like that on Slack.
Yup, you're right. Just tested it.

Comment: And just learned Slack doesn't use Markdown: https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202288908-Formatting-your-messages

Comment: @BorisSerebrov makes a good point. This is a usability problem. What is the least surprising action for your users? If they expect to go to a new line and instead their partially written document is submitted, that could be very aggravating. I have been bitten by this on SO comments as well. There is a good reason for textareas not submitting on [enter].

Comment: @Waylan I talked to my project manager, and I have to use enter for submit. So I'll have to take the long way on this one.